# Integrate Google Apps with WordPress

Tags: google-workspace, wordpress

I have a domain controlled with Google Apps. Now I want `blog.mydomain.com` to be a WordPress blog.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have 2 options both of which require you to use Google-apps [support for mapping your domain](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html) to a google appengine application.

You can use Google Appengine to run Wordpress (it's a bit of an advanced technique) with your Google-apps and assign blog.mydomain.com to your google appengine application.

This blog describes the modifications you need to make to wordpress to run on Google's Datastore and to run PHP through the Java runtime:

[Quercus on Google App Engine](http://blog.caucho.com/?p=196)

You can see it running as Java Google Appengine application:

http://wordpress-on-quercus.appspot.com/wordpress-2.7.1/

> Ever since Google App Engine (GAE)
>   supported Java, it has opened a slew
>   of other languages that GAE indirectly
>   and unofficially supports. PHP is one
>   of them through Quercus, our 100% Java
>   clean-room implementation of the PHP
>   language.
>
> I set to gain insight on this
>   interesting question by getting
>   Wordpress running on GAE. Since
>   Wordpress already runs on Resin with
>   Quercus, all I needed to do was
>   convert the MySQL queries to instead
>   use the App Engine’s subset of JPA. In
>   the end, it took about a week of
>   uneventful work to get enough of
>   Wordpress running so we could demo it
>   at Google I/O.at Google I/O.

Another alternative might be to use Google Appengine as a reverse proxy, mirroring your wordpress hosted site (Google appengine would allow you to handle massive surges in traffic and comes with huge free quotas).

- [bs2grproxy](http://code.google.com/p/bs2grproxy/) - A small app runs on Google App Engine as a reverse proxy to a specific site, completely transparent to clients

Answer (score 1):

I have my mail, calendar etc in Google Apps, but I maintain the DNS from outside this (I didn't know you could do it any other way).

So I have:

- mail.mydomain.com - points to google mail
- cal.mydomain.com - points to google calendar
- blog.mydomain.com - points to my blog - for me this is Wordpress hosted on a server I administer, but it could point at a hosted wordpress.com (as a [Premium Feature](http://en.wordpress.com/products/)) or something else of course.